# Logical error in function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first time around *increment* is 10, like it should be, the second iteration returns *undefined*. I assume that it has got something to do with *setTimeout*?

```
var time = 200;
```

Function:

```
function repeatingfunction(increment) { 
    if (time>5){
        time=time-39
    };
    if (mausunten == true){
        //alert(increment);
        setTimeout(repeatingfunction, time);
        $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", ($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"))+increment); 
        refreshCalculation();
    };
    if (mausunten == false){
        clearTimeout(repeatingfunction);
    };
}
```

Calling and stopping the function:

```
$("#plus1").mousedown(function(){
    mausunten = true;
    repeatingfunction(10);
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    mausunten = false;
    time = 200;
});
```

Comment: If you want quick answers to something like this there are three things you need to do: 1. Create a JSFiddle 2. Create a JSFiddle and lastly 3. Create a JSFiddle :)

Comment: is mausunten declared globally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the value in to subsequent calls.  Try this...

```
var timeoutID;

function repeatingfunction(increment) {
    if (time>5){
        time=time-39
    };
    if (mausunten == true){
        //alert(increment);
        timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
            repeatingfunction(increment);
        }, time);
        $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", ($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"))+increment); 
        refreshCalculation();
    };
    if (mausunten == false){
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    };
}
```

I added a function into setTimeout so that you can pass the value in.

Also, I fixed the clearTimeout.  You were passing the function name into it and it expects an ID that refers to the timer.